# No recovery mode .. Stuck in Fastboot mode (RAMDUMP)

Tags: recovery-mode, fastboot

i have my cherry mobile Omega spectrum ..
i was supposed to reboot my phone after installing a custom 
i can't find any answers in my  group so i decided to post here about this problem anyone here can help me ??
i'm new here ..p thanks a lot

Comment: If you are in fastboot, you should take a look at my answer on [What are all the functions of fastboot](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/93061/1951). Fastboot can allow you to push a recovery image to your device if you don't have one for some reason.

Comment: Could you clarify the question once more? "*after installing a custom*".. ROM or recovery?

Answer (score 1):

As Ryan commented, you can use fastboot commands to push a recovery image to your phone.

download a recovery image for your phone if you don't have one, then connect your phone to your pc and, via the fastboot tool on your computer, type

```
fastboot flash recovery recovery.img
```

where "recovery.img" is the absolute path of your custom recovery image (path is not required if you placed your img in the same directory of your adb-fastboot toolkit).

Afterwards, get into recovery (it should go automatically there if system is missing/corrupted, if not try pressing the power/vol combination for you device)

As you are into recovery, flash your OS as you normally do.

**PS:** before flashing your system via recovery, remember to update your custom recovery, to avoid using a buggy one. Also, be sure to make it check MD5 sums before flashing.

It is also possible that your problem is temporary: a lot of people got through this just by extracting battery, SIM and SD from the phone and then booting normally. Try this before doing anything.